# Trying to add an image using jQuery .load method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load an image called 'mole' using jQuery .load method, however I am not sure if this is the correct method or if there was just a syntax error. Thank you very much for any feedback.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
    $('#mole').load(<img id="mole" src="img/mole.jpg" />);
    });                                                                                             

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`load` is an shorthand for an AJAX `GET` that immediately gets appended to the target element. All you wanted to do is add an image to `#mole`. No AJAX needed here.

```
$('<img id="mole" src="img/mole.jpg" />').appendTo('#mole');
```

Answer (score 0):

**.load()**

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

Source : **[jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**

I think a simple **append()** is more suitable for your purposes.

```
$("#mole").append('<img id="mole" src="img/mole.jpg" />');
```

**Note**

It seems like you already have a `#mole` element on your page, you should not insert a new one with the same ID. The ID property should be unique.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8ucgmb9/)**

Answer (score 0):

`.load()` is suitable for loading HTML from the server asynchronously and inserts it into the matched element.  While you could use this method, it seems that using `.append()` or `.html()` would be more applicable for this situation.

```
$('#mole').append('<img id="mole" src="img/mole.jpg" />')
```

OR

```
$('#mole').html('<img id="mole" src="img/mole.jpg" />')
```

Note that using `.html()` will replace all of the HTML that is within `#mole` while `.append()` will simply append to the end of whatever is already in there.